# "An error occurred while publishing"

Tags: publishing

I'm getting an exception after every publish from CM, but the publishing is happening correctly.

I'm using Sitecore 8.1, Solr Search, and a separate publishing instance.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the patched config section for `publish:end` event. Are there any custom subscribers?

Comment: 1) Check your Sitecore logs and see what publish-related errors you have. Edit your question to include these errors.  
2) If you have any custom Sitecore configuration that may affect publishing, attach that configuration to the question as well.

Comment: Can you go to http://[YourSite]/Sitecore/Admin/ShowConfig.aspx and send us the publish:end section?

Answer (score 4):

There's a couple clues here that I think I can attempt to provide some troubleshooting steps in order to answer your question. Now, before getting too far along, because the error is occurring in the `publish:end` handler all active publishing tasks for the items have already finished which is why it appears the publish was successful.

#### A Few Clues

- You mention you have a separate publishing instance, so going on the assumption you've configured the Scaling config.
- The error details out `publish:end` event handler, which indicates that the issue is within that handler.
- Running Sitecore 8.1 with Solr

#### Taking a look at `publish:end` Events

In a default configuration for Sitecore 8.1 Update 3, we have the following event handlers for `publish:end`:

```xml
<event name="publish:end">
  <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
    <sites hint="list">
      <site>website</site>
    </sites>
  </handler>
  <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.RenderingParametersCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache" />
  <handler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Events.PublishingEventHandler, Sitecore.ContentSearch" method="OnFullPublishEndHandler" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentSearch.config" />
  <handler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Events.PublishingEventHandler, Sitecore.ContentSearch" method="OnPublishHandler" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentSearch.config" />
  <!-- ACTIVE TEST CACHE CLEARER This event handler clears data from the ActiveTest cache -->
  <handler type="Sitecore.ContentTesting.Events.ActiveTestCacheClearer, Sitecore.ContentTesting" method="Process" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentTesting.config" />
  <handler type="Sitecore.Social.Client.MessagePosting.Handlers.PublishEndHandler, Sitecore.Social.Client" method="ClearDbMesageCache" patch:source="Sitecore.Social.config" />
</event>
```

By looking at a default configuration, there are a few places where an error might occur. Again, this is the ***default configuration*** which means the error may be in any kind of custom code that you've created, if you have a custom `publish:end` handler. **Going on the assumption you don't.**

#### Things to Verify

- The site(s) listed for the **HtmlCacheClearer** are accurate to your environment.
- Is SOLR Running at the configured endpoint?

#### Other Potential Causes

- Not with `publish:end` specifically, but I have seen weirdness out of ContentTesting. There is a ContentTesting event handler in the stock configuration. If you wanted to rule out, you could disable this handler in the `Sitecore.ContentTesting.config` file.
- Are you using Glass?  Glass Mapper for Sitecore has a `publish:end` event that clears the Glass Cache. If, for some reason, this cache was unavailable or missing, theoretically it might cause an error.

#### Need more info?

To troubleshoot this further, you'll want to provide the following information:

- Excerpt of Sitecore Log and Publishing Log file during the publish event.
- Copy of your `publish:end` events from `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for you trouble shooting steps, issue was with a custom handler added in the publish:end